# Write Data to File Periodically

Tags: c

I have written this code in C to write data to a text file periodically, but my program won't write it periodically; it  writes to file completely without waiting. I want it to write data to a file, wait ~2 seconds, then write the next line.

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    tm.hh = random() % 23;
    tm.mm = random() % 59;
    tm.ss = random() % 59;

    dt.dd = random() % 31;
    dt.mm = random() % 12;
    dt.yy = random() % 2020;
    if (dt.yy < 2020 && dt.yy > 2015)
    {
        while (dt.yy < 1900)
        {
            dt.yy = random() % 2020;
        }
    }

    val1 = random() % 100;
    val2 = random() % 100;

    fprintf(fp, "%d:%d:%d,%d/%d/%d,%d,%d,\n", tm.hh, tm.mm, tm.ss, dt.dd, dt.mm, dt.yy, val1, val2);
    id = fork();
    if (id == -1)
        printf("error in creating child process\n");
    else if (id == 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        wait(NULL);

}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: What in this code makes you think it's going to wait for any particular amount of time?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the sleep() function right before writing any line.
EDIT: you need to include:

In Windows

```
#include <windows.h>  
Sleep(<timeInMs>);
```

In Unix

```
#include <unistd.h>
sleep(<timeInSeconds>);
```

Comment: Might want to add the needed `#include`s.

Comment: Added @ColonelThirtyTwo ! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Windows `Sleep` needs `#include <windows.h>` not `unistd.h`

Comment: Had forgotten to add that. :)

Comment: thanks it did solve my problem :).